# Weak differentiability

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $v\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ and for every $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$

$|\int_{\Omega}v\phi'dx|\leq C\|\phi\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$

holds. Does it imply that $v$ is weak differentiable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because it is telling you that the functional
$$T(\phi)=-\int_\Omega v\phi^\prime dx,\quad C^1(\Omega)\cap L^2(\Omega)$$
is linear and continuous. So you can first apply Hahn-Banach theorem to extend it to a linear continuous functional $T:L^2(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}$ and then use Riesz representation theorem in $L^2$ to write $T(\phi)=\int_\Omega g\phi\,dx$ for some $g\in L^2(\Omega)$. The function $g$ is the weak derivative of $v$

Comment: Can we deduce that if $(u_{n})\subset H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ converges weakly to some $v\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ with respect to $L^{2}(\Omega)$ norm, then we have $|\int_{\Omega}v\phi'dx|\leq C\|\phi\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$?

Comment: If $u_n$ converges weakly in $H^1_0$ then you know that $v_n$ goes weakly to $v$ in $L^2$ but also that $v'_n$ goes weakly to $g$ in $L^2$. Hence, you can pass to the limit in the integration by parts formula for $f_n$ and do not need to use the result above

Comment: My final goal is to prove that weak convergance of a sequance from $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ implies strong convergance in $L^{2}(\Omega)$. That is why I need the result above.

Comment: For that you have to use Ascoli-Arzela. Since the sequence it is bounded in $H^1_0$ you can prove Holder continuity of exponent 1/2 and using that you get equi-continuity. Equibounded is also not too bad.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see any connection with Ascoli-Arzela theorem. As far as I know it is useful with continuous functions and $H_{0}^{1}$ does not provide that.

Comment: $|u_n(x)-u_n(y)|\le\int_y^x|u'_n(t)|dt\le (y-x)^{1/2}\left(\int_y^x|u'_n(t)|^2 dt\right)$.

Comment: I am not convinced to prove it your way - I just don't see it. Instead, I take into considerations embeddings and compact embeddings. I think that compact embedding may solve the problem with the weak convergance - at least I hope so.